# Accessing an embedded device's GPIO pins via Java SE Embedded

Tags: java, gpio

Is there any library package included in Java SE Embedded to access an embedded device's GPIO pins? or does it vary from board to board?

Comment: Do you mean accessing the GPIOs of a Raspberry Pi?

Comment: @BetaRide no any ARM board, which can run Java and has GPIO

Comment: How did you solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

However, I found out the answer to my question myself, according to [this](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/ma14-new-to-java-embedded-2177732.html) page, accessing GPIO pins is possible by using Java ME Embedded. Java SE Embedded does not provide a built-in library for this purpose.