# How to access GPIO pins in Java?

Tags: java, gpio

Most of the libraries for accessing Java have been written for Raspberry Pi. For example, Pi4j, Framboos etc. They do not work in other hardware. Furthermore I cannot use the jdk.dio library because its full version is not available in Java SE.

I have to access the GPIO pins for AM57x. Can anybody please help me with this?

Comment: It looks like you can't do it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32454655/accessing-an-embedded-devices-gpio-pins-via-java-se-embedded

Comment: So there isn't even a library made by other people that would work? What I mean is a library that is not built in but imported?